# Show the value of one of the object property in different lines and font size

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a JavaScript object with values. While displaying on the webpage, I want to show the values in multiple lines with different font sizes.

Demo link : https://plnkr.co/edit/QQsvz4UJPrRHD84t4CkC?p=preview

object:

```
 $scope.list = [
            {id:'January',description: 'Jan summary \n new line text', start:new Date(2017, 11, 3), end:new Date(2017, 11, 3)},
            {id:'January',description:'ails \n new line text with small font',start:new Date(2018, 1, 3), end:new Date(2018, 2, 3)},
            {id:'February',description: 'feb details1 text here',start: new Date(2017, 11, 17), end:new Date(2017, 11, 17)},
            {id:'February',description: 'February details2 text here2', start: new Date(2017, 11, 17), end:new Date(2017, 11, 17)},
            {id:'may',description: 'may text first data here', start: new Date(2017, 11, 17), end:new Date(2017, 11, 17)},
          ];
```

How to **show the values shown in the description field in multiple lines and different font sizes**.I tried appending `\n` as shown below but now showing the text after `\n` in the new line.
Any inputs...

```
description:'ails \n new line text with small font'
```

Comment: Use HTML. Like, classes or `small` elements.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb - Any sample code would be helpful..demo https://plnkr.co/edit/QQsvz4UJPrRHD84t4CkC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do this would be seperate the description key value pair into an array containing two different strings and then display it using HTML. Like -

description: ['ails','new line text with small font']

```
<div ng-repeat="l in list">
     <h2>l.description[0]</h2>
     <h3>l.description[1]</h3>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!